# What degree does Howard have?

Tags: character, the-big-bang-theory

In The Big Bang Theory, we all know Howard has a Masters Degree in Engineering.  What Engineering subject is his degree in?

Comment: Given that Howard is an aerospace engineer, I suspect his degree is in [Aerospace Engineering](http://catalog.mit.edu/degree-charts/aerospace-engineering-course-16/). (Most likely, he has a Master of Science in Aerospace Engineering, as MIT doesn't offer an "Master of Engineering" specializing in Aerospace)

Answer (score 7):

He has a master's degree in engineering from MIT, but some searching on the internet indicates that that's about the full extent of what's known about it. None of the wikis go into more specifics about what kind of engineering, and the most descriptive quote I've been able to find is this:

> **Howard:** Excuse me, I have a master’s degree in engineering from the Massachusetts Institute of Technology. It required the completion of 144 units of grad work and an original thesis.
>
> <sub>-- [Series 3 Episode 9](https://bigbangtrans.wordpress.com/series-3-episode-09-the-vengeance-formulation/)</sub>

Answer (score 5):

Howard Joel Wolowitz has a Master's degree in Engineering from MIT and as he is **aerospace engineer** .So it refers he has done Masters in Aerospace Engineering as he has also been seen designing important devices like the "space toilet" used at the International Space Station So its ***Aerospace engineering***.